# Relation Gamma function and products

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

I have been thinking about a specific problem for quite some time.
Imagine we have the following product, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ then we now that the following holds:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=k}^{n-1} (x +a +j) = \frac{(x+a+n-1)!}{(x+a+k-1)!}  = \frac{\Gamma(x+a+n)}{\Gamma(x+a+k)}.
\end{align}
What if this $a$ were not to be in $\mathbb{Z}^+$, but rather in $\mathbb{R}^+$, could we then still have a similar expression in terms of the Gamma function?

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ holds even for complex numbers.

Comment: You can group $x+a$ in a single variable, for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. This type of product is common enough in mathematics to have its own notation, the Pochammer symbol, defined as
$$
(a)_n \equiv \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(a+j).
$$
From the Gamma recursion identity $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$, we can write the symbol in terms of the Gamma function:
\begin{multline}
\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)} = (a+n-1)\frac{\Gamma(a+n-1)}{\Gamma(a)} = (a+n-1)(a+n-2)\frac{\Gamma(a+n-2)}{\Gamma(a)}=\,\,...
\\ = (a+n-1)(a+n-2)...(a+1)a\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a)} = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(a+j) = (a)_n.
\end{multline}
Since your product can be written as the Pochhammer symbol $(x+a+k)_{n-k}$, we see that indeed,
$$
\prod_{j=k}^{n-1}(x+a+j) = (x+a+k)_{n-k} = \frac{\Gamma(x+a+n)}{\Gamma(x+a+k)}.
$$